# Can the Apache CXF properties for exceptionMessageCauseEnabled and faultStackTraceEnabled be set dynamically?

Tags: configuration, cxf

I am working on debugging a problem with a [CXF based application](https://www.healthit.gov/FHA/CONNECT). This application is throwing errors like this:

```
[#|2017-07-12T10:52:26.974-0700|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain|_ThreadID=321;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Interceptor for {urn:ihe:iti:xcpd:2009}RespondingGateway_Service#{urn:ihe:iti:xcpd:2009}RespondingGateway_PRPA_IN201305UV02 has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.NullPointerException
|#]
```

I see in this [Apache CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-Configurelogginglevels) that I can set properties for properties for exceptionMessageCauseEnabled and faultStackTraceEnabled. Is it possible to set these properties dynamically or without modifying the cxf.xml configuration file? For example can I pass these parameters as a system property, changing a setting in the application server, or making some sort of external API call?

I reviewed the [source code for CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/source-repository.html) and see that these properties are accessed via a function defined by the `Message` interface and that `MessageImpl` stores these properties in a simple map. What I cannot find is if there is some tool or means to dynamically update that map other than by populating the CXF config file or changing code.

Comment: To be clear, I assume you control both client and server code.  As I understand, those options are only relevant when set on server side.  Have you see this page?  http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html  See section: "Configuring an Endpoint/Client Proxy Using CXF APIs".  I suggest you try to `Map.put(Message.FAULT_STACKTRACE_ENABLED, true)` into whatever maps you can find.  It seems a lot of API objects in CXF derive from `HashMap`.  If you find the correct point to inject, please  kindly share!